# MonoDev deployment issue: AMDeviceInstallApplication returned: 0xe800002d

Tags: xamarin.ios

I had been developing and deploying to various iOS devices without issue using the following toolset:
MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)
    GTK 2.24.10
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 210090011
Apple Developer Tools:
     Xcode 4.3.2 (1177)
     Build 4E2002
Monotouch: 5.2.12
Mono for Android not installed

I updated one of my devices (ipod touch 4G) to iOS 6 in order compare memory usage to iOS 5. I used monoDev to build and upload my app to the iOS 6 ipod however, XCode 4.3.2 Instruments would not connect to the iOS 6 device so I downloaded and ran XCode 4.5 (from the Desktop) and used it's Instruments to analyze my app.

With my test complete I returned to development using an iPad running iOS 5.1.1 but was not able to deploy from MonoDev. I tested using one of the Xamarin sample apps (MediaCapture) with the same results. The error I get when I attempt to "Upload to Device" is as follows:

/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" -installdev "/Users/don/Source/Learning/xamarin-monotouch-samples-eb64016/MediaCapture/MediaCapture/bin/iPhone/Release/MediaCapture.app"
Please ensure your device is connected...
Connected to: iPad2
Initializing file service...
Uploading application
Finalizing file service...
Installing application
Installation failed: AMDeviceInstallApplication returned: 0xe800002d
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP

Using Organizer to look at the console on the iPad I see:

Jul 3 10:50:15 unknown mobile_installation_proxy[126] : main: Could not receive request from host.

Error 0xe800002d is apparently "Failure to Sync" but I have to problem syncing the iPad using iTunes.

The provisioning profiles are all good because I am able to install the same app to the iPad using Organizer and it runs fine. Building and running sample apps using XCode 4.3.2 works fine.

I've tried rebooting everything but that has not helped.

I think this issue must be related to the fact the I ran XCode 4.5 but I don't really see how. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem that happens when you run the latest Xcode 4.5. A system library (MobileDevice.framework [1]) is updated which causes problems for MonoTouch (and since it's a system library it won't help to downgrade Xcode).

It will be fixed in the upcoming MonoTouch 5.3.5 beta, in the meantime you'll have to downgrade your MobileDevice.Framework somehow (maybe from another machine you didn't install Xcode 4.5 on).

[1] /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework

Comment: Copying the framework from another machine worked perfectly. Thank you for that succinct and prompt response!

Comment: Is MonoTouch using the fruitstrap library in order to install applications?

I am experiencing this same issue. It appears that AMDeviceInstallApplication causes the application to exit, without returning a result. If you have made progress in fixing this issue with the newer MobileDevice framework, it would be great to share the results so we can fix the project on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Rolf's answer was right and really saved me hours of time. Thanks! :)

Just want to add that, in case you still have Xcode 4.3 installed, you can run the MobileDevice.framework installation script again, instead of copying from another machine:

> Go to /Applications/ and right click on 'Xcode' and then select 'Show Package Contents' from the popup menu - this will show you the contents of the Xcode.app bundle.
>
> Then go inside Contents and Resources and then Packages (so, your file path should now be /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/) and then double click on the 'MobileDevice.pkg' installer file.

Quoted from [here](http://iphone-ipad-code.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-install-mobile-device-framework-in.html).